# for x in {1..10} in shell script runs only once

Tags: linux, ubuntu, awk, sh

The script below stops after one iteration. How do i make it run 10 times?

```
#!/bin/sh

for a in {1..10}
do
  echo 'a'
  x=`sudo hdparm -t /dev/sda`
  echo $x | awk 'match($0,"= "){print substr($0,RSTART+1)}' >> input.txt
done
```

EDIT:
the `input.txt` will have  `401.98 MB/sec ...`, A list of read speeds.

Comment: What do you get if you just run `for a in {1..10}; do echo $a; done`

Comment: `echo 'a'` is not `echo "$a"`.

Comment: ...also, why capture `x` and then emit it, rather than running `sudo hdparm -t /dev/sda | awk ...`? `echo $x` is a bit buggy -- would need to be `echo "$x"` to preserve newlines and other formatting -- but if you were doing it right, that bug wouldn't matter, since there would be no such echo needed.

Comment: @ilent2 print 1 till 10

Comment: @CharlesDuffy echo 'a' is just printing "a" 10 times. It prints once. Also, the individual commands works just fine.

Comment: Only "just fine" if newlines don't matter in hdparm's output, since you're throwing them away to be replaced with spaces. I haven't looked closely enough at what you're doing with awk to know if that is or isn't fine for your use case, admittedly.

Comment: As for the behavior (of your loop not looping) -- can't reproduce that using the exact code given; I get a proper 10 invocations.

Comment: Ok, it works if i copy the script in bash. If i run as a sh file.sh, it stops at one iteration.

Comment: @EdMorton yes, you are correct. It treats it as a string.

Comment: If you put a shebang on a script (as `#!/bin/bash` was originally given here), folks are likely to assume you're running it as `./yourscript`, as the shebang allows, and thus that the interpreter specified in the shebang is genuinely the one in use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sh` is treating the bashism `{1..10}` as a string so `for a in {1..10}` sets `a` to the string `{1..10}` loops once then quits. You'd have caught that yourself if you'd used `echo "$a"` instead of `echo 'a'` as @CharlesDuffy suggested immediately when you posted the question. Hopefully you know now it's important to tell us the actual shell you are using when asking a question, had you tagged this as `sh` instead of `bash` I'm sure you'd have got the answer immediately.

Comment: how would `{1..10}` be used in sh ?

Comment: Are you asking how to implement the equivalent of bash's `{1..10}` in shell or are you asking what shell interprets the text `{1..10}` as meaning?

Comment: Yes, that's why I came to this question

Comment: I asked you an either-or question and you answered "yes". I suggest you open a new question and refer to this one if you like but make sure your new question stands alone.

Comment: I'm sorry for not reading properly. I would like to know how `{1..10}`  could be used in shell script or if there's an equal solution for generating an iterable range